# Using debounceTime in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I want to use `debounceTime` for sending a request to the sever after 300 milisecond of pressing a key.

I use this code:

```
GetUsers(): void {
    let value = document.getElementById('search-box');
    this.cdRef.detectChanges();

    if (this.subscription) {
        this.subscription.unsubscribe();
    }

    value = this.searchValue.toString();

    const typeahead = fromEvent(value, 'input').pipe(
        map((e: KeyboardEvent) => (e.target as HTMLInputElement).value),
        filter(text => text.length > 2),
        debounceTime(10),
        distinctUntilChanged(),
        x => {
            if (value.startsWith('@')) {
                this.searchTitle = 'GENERAL.USER_NAME';
                const val = value.slice(1);
                if (val.length > 0) {

                    this.getWithUserName(val, this.page);

                }
            } else if (value.startsWith('+9')) {

                this.searchTitle = 'GENERAL.PHONE_NUMBER';
                this.GetWithPhoneNumber(this.searchValue, this.page);

            } else if (!value.startsWith('@') && !value.startsWith('+9')) {
                this.searchTitle = 'GENERAL.NAME';
                this.GetWithDisplayName(value, this.page);

            }
        }
    );
    this.cdRef.detectChanges();
}
```

and this is code `HttpClient` for send request to server:

```
getWithUserName(value: string, page: number): void {
    this.loading = true;
    this.cdRef.detectChanges();
    this.subscription = this.userPublicService
        .getUserByUserName(value, page, this.appConfig.dropdownPageSize)
        .pipe(debounceTime(30000),
            distinctUntilChanged())
        .subscribe(data => {
            this.users = data['records'];
            this.totalCount = data['totalCount'];
            this.cdRef.detectChanges();
            this.loading = false;
            this.ValidateshowBtn();
        });
    if (this.userId > 0) {
        this.selectedUserById(this.userId);
    }
}
```

But this code does not work for me.

What's the problem? How can I solve this problem?

it show me this error :

> ERROR in src/app/shared/components/user-mutli-select-search/user-mutli-select-search.component.ts(117,4): error TS2345: Argument of type '(x: Observable) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'OperatorFunction'.
>         Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'Observable<{}>'.

Comment: You need to debug it further to isolate *exactly* "what is not working". You may have done that, but "all of this does not work for me" is too vague. What does work? What does it do? Where is the issue? Narrow it down to the exact problem and the minimal reproducer.

Comment: @JoshWulf it show me this error . i update the question

Comment: OK, great! So which line is that (117) in the code that you've posted?

Comment: https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/http/search_with_switchmap

Answer (score 1):

Typing `fromEvent` as `fromEvent<KeyboardEvent>` fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

The function that starts with `x => {` should be inside `tap()` or in the `subscribe()`.

Comment: ..or return an Observable.